# Can the android use BroadcastReceiver to play music without Service?

Tags: android, broadcast

Same as the title.
I want to use `sendBroadcast(intent)` to start broadcast;
and then in the `broadcast.java` use the `onReceive()`, like so:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
 {    
        Toast.makeText(context, "successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.canon).start();    
  }
```

But VM can not do it, and it says: `the media unable to create....`
I'm a beginner, I don't know how to deal with it.
Please help me, thank you :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you are not supposed to start anything asynchronous or long running in `onReceive`. If you need to run something in background, then use `Service`.

That's because as soon as `onReceive` returns, the component is considered dead. So no background operations are allowed to be tied to this component. And even more, Android can kill process as soon as `onReceive` returns if this was the only component in process.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can.

However, this is bad practice as media playback can be a computationally intensive task.

If you attempt to fetch and playback media in the main thread of an application, you will very likely get the dreaded "bluescreen" of Android, the Application Not Responding, firce close error.

EDIT:

An important note:

Generally, you want to use a ContentProvider rather than trying to access large files like music directly.

Comment: thanks for your answer,it helps a lot. I think i should study a lot to improve myself and not be stuck in it now.

Comment: No problem.  Please mark an answer as "correct" and/or upvote it if it answered your question.  Hope you're enjoying SO!